# Изменить параметры material файла

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, material

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста:
Создан файл my_material.mat c помощью кода:

```
    public void CreateMaterial(string pathToSave)
    {
        string fullPath = pathToSave + "New Material" + ".txt";
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            string fileParams = "";
            byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(fileParams);
            fileStream.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
        }
        File.Move(fullPath, pathToSave + "New Material" + ".mat");
    }
```

Нужно изменить у Material объекта параметр Shader на Skybox / cubemap в коде.
[image]

В документации не могу найти уже долгое время.